# Linux sometimes halts and I can't do anything

Tags: linux, halts

I've got problem.
I'm using old KBS-MX motherboard and feel 300ATX powersupply.
Sometimes when I'm doing something, sometimes I hear sound in my loudspeaker like it got plugged off of computer and my computer stops. I can't do anything even mouse and keyboard is not working everything stops.
Do you know what could be the problem?

PS: I've got the newest linux.

Comment: by "I've got the newest linux" ... what do you mean? Which distribution? What release?

Answer (score 3):

Well ... first, check the logs (/var/log/...) 
Second I would suspect the power supply. Does this happen when your computer is more stressed?
Third there may be some problems with the RAM.
And finally I would check for CPU overheating.